# Modify Bluemix nodejs buildpack

Tags: java, node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I'm looking to modify the NodeJS Buildpack in Bluemix. I want to run a nodeJS runtime with Java in it. Has anyone tried this before?

I found this buildpack, running nodeJS and Java 8. I tried to build from the buildpack but it doesn't seem to work

`cf push <app_name> -b https://github.com/syahrul-aiman/nodejs-java-buildpack -s cflinuxfs2`

I want to add java because I have a JAR file that will perform file merging operations triggered by my nodeJS apps.

```
Downloading and installing node 0.12.11... 
Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/concourse-binar‌​ies/node/node-0.12.1‌​1-linux-x64.tgz] 
Using default npm version: 2.14.9 
Downloading JAVA [http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u73-b02/jdk-8u‌​73-linux-x64.tar.gz]
Download complete! 
Installing JAVA 
Download complete! 
Installing Maven 
Downloading CF CLI [https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&so‌​urce=github] 
Installation complete! 
Download complete!
```

Comment: In which way does this not work? Can you provide logs please?

Comment: `Downloading and installing node 0.12.11...`
`Downloaded [https://pivotal-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/concourse-binaries/node/node-0.12.11-linux-x64.tgz]`
`Using default npm version: 2.14.9`
`Downloading JAVA [http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u73-b02/jdk-8u73-linux-x64.tar.gz]`
`Download complete!`
`Installing JAVA`
`Download complete!`
`Installing Maven`
`Downloading CF CLI [https://cli.run.pivotal.io/stable?release=linux64-binary&source=github]`
`Installation complete!`
`Download complete!`

That installed Java but won't run my express app anymore.

Comment: Error logs? Error message?

Comment: Thanks @EngineerBetter for the formatting. Anyway, I managed to install Java and the buildpack above works perfectly fine. I had to increase the memory usage of every instance of the operation we are doing is actually memory intensive. I'm thinking of running another cf app with the java runtime.